# Apache (wamp) server redirecting to old url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, wamp, phpbb

I had a server running WAMP, that served many phpBB forums. The HD went dead in 2010, but recently i was able to recover the whole data.

I put the old installation dir /wamp/ on same path it was before, run `wampmanager.exe`, server goes up and the website and the forums work fine as they were like in 2010. However, one of them was successful, and that one specifically don't work normally.

The directory structure is:

- /AllSites/Foo/
- /AllSites/Bar/
- /AllSites/GoodSite/

/AllSites/ is an auto-generated apache index, that shows the forum folders (Foo, Bar, GoodSite).

When i navigate to to `localhost/AllSites/GoodSite/`, i see the browser requesting from `http://old.no-ip.url/AllSites/GoodSite`, and not from localhost, until it obviously timeouts.

Naturally, i went to GoodSite's phpBB configuration to check if the `old.no-ip.url` was being set somewhere. Not there, and not via MySQL search for `old.no-ip.url` string (phpBB actually only asks for /path/, not domain). So i tried to navigate manually to `http://localhost/AllSites/GoodSite/index.php` and my surprise, entering like that the site works fine and always stay at localhost.

That made me abandon phpBB as the cause of the issue and focus on Apache (i can even remove index.php from /GoodSite/ and it redirects).

Next thing, i went to `.htaccess` in /AllSites/ and saw `Redirect permanent /AllSites/GoodSite http://old.no-ip.url/AllSites/GoodSite`. I removed the line, restarted server, refreshed browser cache, but nothing. It always try to go to the old url when navigating to the GoodSite folder.

So i searched for `old.no-ip.url` in the *whole* xamp directory (maybe an alias set somewhere) and subdirectories files', for no result (using Notepad++ "Find in Files" option).

So what can be causing this? The only thing that could be redirecting at server level would be apache or maybe php. But there's no such setting, as the Notepad++ search confirmed. Maybe there is something cached? I ran out of solutions. I even tried deleting the `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Have you checked your host file???

Comment: httpd-vhosts vontains no VirtualHosts beside the default. Also the Notepad++ search for the string `old.no-ip.url` would have found it. It's mind-boggling.

Comment: I meant the OS host file, in windows it's in system32/drivers/etc

Comment: Oh i see. That is also default. I am running the old WAMP in my laptop, just had to put it on same local path. All settings OUTSIDE /wamp/ directory can be safely excluded. The only things that could be doing this at *C:\wamp\* are: Some php redirect (Notepad++ search excluded it, and i wouldn't do it that way, i used .htaccess for that); Some apache configuration (Notepad++ search excluded it). I did tried other searches in Notepad++ to check reliability, and it works fine. I can only thing of some cache-style problem. How can i clear all WAMP caches?

Comment: please paste htaccess

Comment: I deleted .htaccess, started server and have same behavior. The link of /AllSite/GoodSite is localhost, but when i click it, even without /GoodSite/index.php present, it does the redirect. It's in a "limbo" state. I just can't understand WHERE it gets the redirect or its address, it just isn't present anywhere.

Comment: Did you check the HOST file ?